# alsaaudio library not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyalsaaudio

Has the alsaaudio library been ported to python3? i have this working on python 2.7 but not on python 3.
is there another library for python 3 if the above cannot be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have compiled alsaaudio for python3 manually.

You can install it by following the steps given below.

1. Make sure that **gcc, python3-dev, libasound2-dev** packages are installed in your machine (install them using synaptic if you are using Ubuntu).
2. Download and extract the following package 
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyalsaaudio/files/pyalsaaudio-0.7.tar.gz/download
3. Go to the extracted folder and execute the following commands (Execute the commands as root or use sudo)

```
python3 setup.py build 
python3 setup.py install
```

HTH..

Answer (score 4):

It's now called pyalsaaudio.
For me pip install pyalsaaudio worked.